# Mongo - How to return collection where field is in another collection array?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, coffeescript

I'm using Meteor with Mongo.
I have a Notifications collection, which I'm inserting into with the following code (coffeescript) -

```
    Notifications.new
      title: Meteor.user().username + ' liked your listing'
      link: '/listing/' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('doc')
      icon: 'thumbs-up'
      class: 'default'
      target: $(e.currentTarget).attr('doc')
```

Essentially what I want to do is return notifications to the user who created the listing ('target' field in collection is the listing id).

I tried inserting $(e.currentTarget).attr('doc').createdBy but alas it did not work. (I'm new to this stuff)

If I can find a way to insert the createdBy in the notification, everything will come together better, but I can't figure out a way to do it.

My other idea was to try and do something like this  - 
I've got a listings array within my user collection *

```
Meteor.publish 'notifications', ->
   Notifications.find {**** return Notifications where their target ID is in the current User listing array ****}
```

Anybody have any ideas for this?
Appreciate it so much.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to first lookup the listing and get the `_id` of the user who created it:

```
let listingId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('doc');

// assuming that the Listings collection has such a key
// AND that the Listing referred to is published to the current user

let createdById = Listings.findOne(listingId).createdById;

Notifications.new
  title: Meteor.user().username + ' liked your listing'
  link: '/listing/' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('doc')
  icon: 'thumbs-up'
  class: 'default'
  target: createdById
```

If you are not tracking the creator's `_id` in the listing document but are instead tracking what listings were created in the user document then you need to search the `Meteor.users` collection instead:

```
let createdById = Meteor.users.findOne({listings: listingId})._id;
```